# RecyclerView multi selection - Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection

I have `RecyclerView` with items. For that `RecyclerView` I'm creating my custom adapter. When I select one row I change background color of that view. The problem is when `RecyclerView` have lot of items, when I click on one row, the application change background color of that view, but it also change background color on another row.

My adapter code:

```
public class NarackiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NarackiAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<TableItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TableItems> selected = new ArrayList<>();

    public NarackiAdapter(Context context, List<TableItems> items) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final TableItems item = items.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(item.getQuantity() + " " + item.getProducts().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView tvName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (getBackgroundColor(view) == R.color.primary) {
                view.setBackgroundResoucre(R.color.light_gray);
                selected.remove(items.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundResoucre(R.color.primary);
                selected.add(items.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Kotlin users, the following article might be useful [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have do the logic of changing color acording if selected or not in your onBindViewHolder() also because the recycler reuse the same view and you have to update it there. When scrolling the onBindViewHolder() will be triggered so you will need to check if view in current position is selected or not.

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final TableItems item = items.get(position);
     //checkIfSelected(item) should check in your selected items array if this item exist there
    if(checkIfSelected(item)){
       //This will be the view that you want to update background 
       view.setBackgroundResoucre(R.color.primary);
    }else{
      //This will be the view that you want to update background 
       view.setBackgroundResoucre(R.color.light_gray);
    }   
    holder.tvName.setText(item.getQuantity() + " " + item.getProducts().getName());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`RecyclerView` reuses views! Therefore if you change the `backgroundColor` of one view, when `RecyclerView` reuses that view, the reuse will have the same `backgroundcolor`.
The way around this buggy behaviour is implementing holder changes in the `bindViewHolder` method because it is called every time a view is reused.
Therefore, the `bindViewHolder` method should evaluate data and decide how the view.
And your `onClick` function should edit this data and call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition)` or `adapter.NotifyDataChanged()`